# Solving $u_t=ku_{xx}$ for $\ t\ge 0,-\infty<x<\infty$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> Solve $$u_t=ku_{xx}\\u(x,0)=g(x)$$ for $t\ge 0, -\infty<x<\infty$, where $$g(x) = \begin{cases}
> 1, \quad \lvert x \rvert < 1 \\
> 0, \quad \lvert x \rvert > 1
> \end{cases}$$

Solution.

We have that the solution is given by 
\begin{align}
u(x,t) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}}\int_{-1}^1e^{-(x-y)^2/4kt} \cdot 1 dy \\
&= \frac{-1}{\sqrt\pi}\int_{\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{4kt}}}^{\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{4kt}}} e^{-p^2}dp
\end{align}
if we consider  $p=\frac{(x-y)}{\sqrt{4kt}}$ in the solution formula.

Is my solution correct so far? If yes, how do I integrate the integral with the $p$ variable?

I was thinking to separate the integral like

$$\int_{-a}^a=\int_{-a}^0+\int_0^a$$

but I'm not sure that

$$\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{4kt}}<0$$

Comment: An integral of a Gaussian over finite limits cannot be represented in terms of elementary mathematical functions. The best you can do is represent it as the error function or leave the integral as is.

Comment: @MasterYoda ok. so what do I write then?

Comment: You can keep the integral as it is, or rewrite it in terms of the error function which is defined as $$\text{erf}(z):=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^ze^{-t^2}dt$$

Comment: @MasterYoda How will I get the $0$ as lower limit of the integral if I write the integral in terms of $erf(z)$ ?

Comment: I responded to your question as an answer. See below.

Comment: @MasterYoda Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question on how to rewrite the integral in terms of the error function, you are close to the result. To start, you already recognized that
$$\begin{align}
u(x,t) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}\right)\,g(y)\,dy\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}}\int_{|x|<1}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}\right)(1)\,dy + \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}}\int_{|x|>1}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}\right)(0)\,dy\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi kt}}\int_{-1}^1\exp\left(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4kt}\right)\,dy
\end{align}$$
is the solution to the given PDE given the boundary conditions. Applying the change of variable $p = \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{4kt}}$ gives
$$u(x,t) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{4kt}}}^{\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{4kt}}}e^{-p^2}dp$$
Now split up the integral as per your intuition told you.
$$u(x,t) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left[\int_0^{\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{4kt}}}e^{-p^2}dp+\int_{\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{4kt}}}^0e^{-p^2}dp\right]
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left[\int_0^{\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{4kt}}}e^{-p^2}dp-\int_0^{\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{4kt}}}e^{-p^2}dp\right]$$
Applying the definition of the error function in the comments above will give the simply represented solution to the PDE.
$$\begin{align}
u(x,t) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\left[\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\text{ erf}\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{4kt}}\right)-\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\text{ erf}\left(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{4kt}}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\text{ erf}\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{4kt}}\right)-\text{ erf}\left(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{4kt}}\right)\right]
\end{align}$$
Here is a quick and dirty graphical solution of the PDE using the error function. Notice it has a maximum value of $1$ at $t=0$ (boundary condition) and the curve decreases as time passes. This is the general behavior of the heat/dilution equation.
[image]

Comment: After the change of variable using $p = \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{4kt}}$ isn't the answer $u(x,t) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{4kt}}}^{\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{4kt}}}e^{-p^2}dp$ instead of $u(x,t) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{4kt}}}^{\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{4kt}}}e^{-p^2}dp$ ?

Comment: When you split up the integral, how do you know that $\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{4kt}}>0$ and $\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{4kt}}<0$ ?

Comment: Nice graph btw :)

Comment: In $y$ coordinates, $y = -1$ is lower limit. Plug this into $p$ for the lower limit $\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{4kt}}$ in $p$ space. It is not necessarily saying one is greater than the other, because that changes depending on if we are on the left half line $(x<0)$ versus the right half line $(x>0)$. It is just a consequence of the chosen change of variables. If we chose $q=\frac{y-x}{\sqrt{4kt}}$ as our new variable instead, then the limits would be flipped with no negative in front, which is exactly the same result. So it's just because of the choice of variable change.

Comment: I still don't get why there's no problem splitting up the integral like you did, how do you know  one of this $\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{4kt}}$ must be after 0 and $\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{4kt}}$ before 0?. Why the possibility of both of them to be after (or before) 0 doesn't exist?

Comment: Why here $u(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}\left[\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\text{ erf}\left(\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{4kt}}\right)-\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\text{ erf}\left(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{4kt}}\right)\right]$ you wrote $\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$ instead of $\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}$ ?